# Low latency when connecting to a local host, but I get chunks of data 3 times a sec when using an external host

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I have a project that transmits a stream of small data packets, <32 bytes, every 10-12 ms. When I send the data from the client on the computer to the host on the same computer using the IP address, not localhost mind you, I get no problems and the response is fast. However, when I connect to any source outside the machine I get the data only 3 times a second. This is weird as I have 100MB/s transfer when transporting files and the network works. I tried using a direct connection using both an USB connection and an Ethernet connection. I tried WiFi as well. They all gave me updates only 3 times per second. I isolated the network in each case.

I also tried different programs, one written in C++ and the other in python, to see if my implementation was wrong, but nothing changed. Since it works when I connect locally I cant see how the programming and network code is to blame.

I tried updating drivers, but that did not fix it. I tried building a new desktop with exactly the same components and software. It works on that PC.

I am honestly at a loss as I can not find a single pattern or explanation, not to mention a solution, for this annoying problem.

What can cause such a behaviour? It cant be the buffer as it works locally? I tried changing it and making the client send data only 10 times per sec. It shouldn't be packet loss as I am using TCP on a local network without wireless. Two PCs and one Ethernet cord.

Everything else works fine and snappy with web pages loading fast and YouTube videos loading fast. Downloads and uploads are also fast.

This problem is driving me insane. Please save my sanity.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `TCP_NODELAY` option to disable the Nagle Algorithm? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: Wireshark, traceroute, ping, there are various tools for network traffic analysis. There are many reasons that could cause in latency phenomenons.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use localhost or any other local IP address, local traffic will go via the loopback pseudo-interface, and will not show the same characteristics as real network traffic.

Comment: @Barmar Should it not effect the other PC as well if that was the case? I checked and The option was set.

Comment: @AlanStokes Could you point me to some litterature on the differences between internal vs. external networking? Are some layers of the OSI model skipped etc? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where it's written, but it can take lots of shortcuts when the source and destination are on the same machine. Since the same software works on a different machine, it sounds like an issue with the NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nagling turned on. This is the default. It batches up data and sends it out every 200ms. So it really is 5 Hz, not 3 Hz as you estimated.

Disable nagling. Be careful because now each and every end will result in a network packet.

Comment: Then how can another identical PC have no issues when it is running the same code compiled by the same compiler using the same OS on the same hardware with the same drivers and updates? I will look into it, though. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the OS is not doing nagling on localhost. Why would it.

Comment: That is not what I mean. I have another identical PC that does not have any issues with streaming data from an external source. In other words NOT to a localhost. Could the OS be set to default to have nagling turned off?

Comment: I don's think there is such an option because it would only break applications. I don't fully understand all the observations you made. Nagling only comes into effect for data less than one packet in size in total. Maybe it's not nagling, your test will tell.

Comment: It was nagling. I didnt see any difference because someone had changed the name of the software so I reinstalled the program that I was not using. The moment I reinstalled everything I managed to get it to run butter smooth. Thanks.

Comment: This is not good advice. Disabling Nagling is a last resort when other methods fail and should really only be used for protocols not designed to be used over TCP. Poor latency is a sign of poor protocol design that should be fixed at the protocol design level if possible and only resorting to wasting network bandwidth if such an improvement isn't possible for some reason. (For example, if it's a legacy protocol you can't fix.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `I have a project that transmits a stream of small data packets, <32 bytes, every 10-12 ms.` How would you address that without disabling nagling?

Comment: @usr By designing the protocol such that there are return packets for the ACKs to piggy-back onto. (That is, design the protocol so that it layers properly on top of TCP, rather than disabling Nagling which can cause pathological behavior.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that does not fix the 200ms latency when sending, does it? Even if it did it is not at all wrong to chunk the packets exactly as you want them. Nagling is not a property of TCP at all, it's a property of the TCP implementation. Nagling cannot be detected by the application except as a quality of implementation issue. Please explain, *why* you feel not using Nagling is unclean. His explicit requirement is that the data is sent *without any delay*.

Comment: @usr It fixes the latency when sending. The first chunk will be sent immediately. The ACK will piggyback on the application-level acknowledgement, allowing the second chunk to be sent immediately as well. Not using Nagling is unclean because you need Nagle to avoid pathological behavior when, for example, ACKs get dropped. You should only disable Nagle when, for some reason, you can't design a protocol to work with TCP sanely. Nagle serves an important purpose and disabling it should be a last resort. Here, there's a much better way to fix the problem without losing the advantages of Nagle.

Comment: I do not see any second chunk. His app generates a tiny "ping" every few milliseconds. There is nothing to coalesce under any circumstances, Nagling or not. If pings are coalesced it's a perf bug for him. @DavidSchwartz I will look into the packet drop issue you mention since it interests me. I stand by my recommendation, though, since nothing else gives him the latency he *requires*.

Comment: @usr Application-level acknowledgements do. Did you read what I wrote? An application-level acknowledgement allows the ACK to piggyback. That's how properly-designed protocols layered over TCP work. Disabling Nagle is a dangerous hack that's only suitable when you have no control over the protocol.